# On click of the tab form the HTML table and attach to the corresponding tab

Tags: jquery

I have a set of **tabs**  on click of the tab , i am fetching the symbols related to that tab , and then sending each symbol to the server and finally forming a html **table** dynamically .

Now how can  i  append that dynamically created  table to the clicked tab .

similar to this fiddle functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/3618/

some part of my code

```
function fetchData(clickedtab)
{
    var emptyarray = [];
    emptyarray.length = 0;
    if (clickedtab === '#tab-1')
    {
        emptyarray = tab1_symbols.slice();
    }
    else if (clickedtab === '#tab-2')
    {
        emptyarray = tab2_symbols.slice();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < emptyarray.length; i++)
    {
        var symbol_array = emptyarray[i];
        ajaxresponsefromserver(symbol_array);
    }
}
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/3623/

But i dont have any idea on how to form this .

Could you please let me know how to form this

Comment: do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t8xp3mn0/

Comment: Can't you pass all the symbols array at once to `ajaxresponsefromserver` method and form the `table` as well in that method?